# pass template from a .vue file to another .vue file

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to follow [this](https://vuejsfeed.com/blog/modal-component-for-semantic-ui) tutorial. I am getting a `Modal` using below code.

```
<modal 
    v-model="showModal" 
    :animation-duration="animationDuration" 
    :close-on-click-away="closeOnClickAway"
    >

    <p slot="header">Confirmation needed</p>

    <p slot="content">Do you want to continue?</p>

    <template slot="actions">
        <div class="ui black deny button" 
            @click="showModal=false">
            No
        </div>
        <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button" 
            @click="confirm">
            Yes
            <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
        </div>
    </template>
</modal>
```

Here I would like to place below portion of the code in another `.vue` file named `ModalBody.vue`.

```
<p slot="header">Confirmation needed</p>

<p slot="content">Do you want to continue?</p>

<template slot="actions">
    <div class="ui black deny button" 
        @click="showModal=false">
        No
    </div>
    <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button" 
        @click="confirm">
        Yes
        <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then I am trying to access that file like below

```
           <modal 
            v-model="showModal" 
            :animation-duration="animationDuration" 
            :close-on-click-away="closeOnClickAway"
            > 
            <modal-body></modal-body>                                         
        </modal>
```

But it is not working. Even I am not getting any error in console.

**UPDATE**

`Parent.vue`

```
<template>
        <modal 
            v-model="showModal" 
            :animation-duration="animationDuration" 
            :close-on-click-away="closeOnClickAway"
            > 
            <modal-body></modal-body>                                         
        </modal>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import ModalBody from './ModalBody';
    export default {
        components: { ModalBody },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```
<template>
   <!-- html code -->
   <modal-body v-show="showModal"></modal-body>                                         
</template>

<script>
import modalBody from './ModalBody'

export default {
    components: {
       childComponent
    },
    data: () => ({ showModal: false })
} 
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

I committed mistakes, but your noticed her.

your updated code have mistakes too

1. tag `</div>`
2. `<modal>` - is a component

so

Parent.vue

```
<template>
    <modal 
        v-model="showModal" 
        :animation-duration="animationDuration" 
        :close-on-click-away="closeOnClickAway"
        > 
        <modal-body></modal-body>                                         
    </modal>
</template>

<script>
import ModalBody from './ModalBody';
import modal from './modal';

export default {
    components: { 
        ModalBody,
        modal 
    }
/* component code */
}
</script>
```

**important!**
*If you want to insert another component or element into the component, then inside this component there must be a `<slot></slot>`*. [see](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Single-Slot)

also see my example app: https://codesandbox.io/s/3xyx386q65

open '*components/setProps/setProps.vue*'

Comment: `childComponent` should be `modalBody`, also its unclear if they've established a way to toggle the value of `showModal`...

Comment: Thanks @Volodymyr Synmonenko for your reply.  Your solution is not working. I updated my question. I think that will be helpful for you.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @VolodymyrSymonenko for your reply. I wrote code like you but I did mistake at the time of code pasting. But unfortunately your code is not working. Even I am trying to use `<slot>` but I am not getting required output. Thanks